# I need a query to get date from a comment string in teradata irrespective of its postion

Tags: sql, teradata

example:
comment is ' Drop table on 12-09-2010 '
or 
comment is '12-09-2010 '
or
comment is ' Drop  12-09-2010'

Answer should be date format irrespective of where position of field comes in teradata

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REGXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/bSkgRmSt8P48II0SKyyH3Q). Based on your MM-DD-YYYY date format, it should be:

```
regexp_substr(<your column>,'((0|1)\d{1})-((0|1|2)\d{1})-((19|20)\d{2})')
```

EDIT:
Here's a slightly better regex, it'll get closer to handling invalid dates. I don't think any regex can tell you that something like 2020-02-30 is not a legit date.

```
regexp_substr(some_col,'(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-[0-9]{4}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an 'extract date from string' function. You need to break the string apart:
          STRTOK(col,'delim',1), STRTOK(col,'delim',2), STRTOK(col,'delim',3)

or check out the:
REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE